# Android app did not receive data from SignalR hub

Tags: java, c#, android, signalr, chat

I already read these topics:
[how to use SignalR in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573823/how-to-use-signalr-in-android/32574829#32574829)
[Android Client doesn't get data but .net client getting data from SignalR server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375453/android-client-doesnt-get-data-but-net-client-getting-data-from-signalr-server)

I write a simple chat system with Android that works with SignalR.
It is supposed to the clients send messages (by calling `SendMessage` method on the server) and the server should call the `NewMessage` method on the clients.

Here is my `ChatHub` class (simplified) written in C#.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    // Store the clients connections Id
    static readonly List<string> _connectedClients;

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        // Keep connections id
        // This section works fine and when the android device connects to the server,
        // Its connection id will stored.
        _connectedClients.Add(Context.ConnectionId)

        //... other codes
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        foreach (var connectionId in _connectedClients)
        {
            // according to the logs 
            // android device connection id exists here
            // and it works fine.
            Clients.Client(connectionId).NewMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When the android client connects to the server, On the `OnConnected` method, the connection id will be stored in the `_connectedClients` and it works fine.

In the `SendMessage` method of the `ChatHub` class, We have the android device connection id, and I'm sure that the android device is within the list

And here is my Andoird codes:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // private fields
    HubConnection connection;
    HubProxy hub;
    ClientTransport transport;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Logger logger = new Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message, LogLevel logLevel) {
                Log.e("SignalR", message);
            }
        };

        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        connection = new HubConnection("192.168.1.100");
        hub = connection.createHubProxy("chatHub"); // case insensitivity

        transport = new LongPollingTransport(connection.getLogger());

        // no difference when using this:
        //transport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger());

        // this event never fired!
        hub.subscribe(new Object() {
            public void NewMessage(String message)
            {
                Log.d("<Debug", "new message received in subscribe"); // won't work!
            }
        }

        // this event never fired!
        hub.on("NewMessage", new SubscriptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("<Debug", "new message received in `on`"); // won't work!
            }
        });

        // connect to the server that works fine.
        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start(transport);
        try {
            awaitConnection.get(); // seems useless when using this or not!
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        // this method works fine.
        hub.invoke("sendMessage", "this is a test message to the server")
        .done(new Action<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void run(Void aVoid) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("<Debug", "message sent."); // Works fine
                }
        });

    }
}
```

In the above **java** code, invoking the `sendMessage` on the server works fine and the server get the messages.
But the only problem is that the `hub.on(...)` or `hub.subscribe(...)` events are never be called by the server.
In a simple description, My app can send message, but can not receive message from the others.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42527962/1770868

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the futures this is the way I finally achieved the answer (please first read the question android codes):

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // private fields
    HubConnection connection;
    HubProxy hub;
    ClientTransport transport;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Logger logger = new Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message, LogLevel logLevel) {
                Log.e("SignalR", message);
            }
        };

        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        connection = new HubConnection("192.168.1.100");
        hub = connection.createHubProxy("chatHub"); // case insensitivity

        /* ****new codes here**** */
        hub.subscribe(this);

        transport = new LongPollingTransport(connection.getLogger());

        /* ****new codes here**** */
        connection.start(transport);

        /* ****new codes here**** */
        /* ****seems useless but should be here!**** */
        hub.subscribe(new Object() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void newMessage(final String message, final String messageId, final String chatId,
                                   final String senderUserId, final String fileUrl, final String replyToMessageId) {


            }
        });


        /* ********************** */
        /* ****new codes here**** */
        /* **** the main method that I fetch data from server**** */
        connection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(final JsonElement json) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
                        Log.e("<Debug>", "response = " + jsonObject.toString());

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        /* ********************** */

    }
}
```

**!important note:**
The priority of the codes is important. this is how I fix my problem in this topic.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer I was facing same issue and it solved mine. I get the response from server in "onMessageReceived" method..which i wasnt expected.. Anyway I observed that the connection breaks down and I stop receiving messages after a while.. what can be the reason for it ?

Comment: In the server in our `startup` class in the `Configuration` method we write these: `GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(110);   GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);  GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);`. We are using WebApi by the way. @UmarFarooque

Answer (score 4):

You does not provider parameters in your client-side which should be **same** as your side-site.  The code should be below:

```
      hub.on("NewMessage", new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void run(String message) {
            Log.d("<Debug", "new message received in `on`"); 
        }
    },String.class);  //do not forget say the String class in the end
```